Problem with Focus widgets behavior in flutter
I am developing an app for Android TV using flutter. I am currently working on the login page which has three widgets. I wrapped the form widget with a FocusableActionDetector Widget.
This the shortcuts Map
shortcuts: {
    LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.select): const ActivateIntent(),
    LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp):  UpbuttonIntent(),
    LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowDown):  DownbuttonIntent(),
  }

These are the actions
 actions: <Type, Action<Intent>>{
    DownbuttonIntent: CallbackAction<DownbuttonIntent>(
      onInvoke: (intent) {
         if(usernameFocus!.hasFocus){
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(passwordFocus);
            setState(() {
              
            });
        }else if(passwordFocus!.hasFocus){
           FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(loginButtonFocus);
           setState(() {
             
           });
        }else if(loginButtonFocus!.hasFocus){
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(usernameFocus);
          setState(() {
            
          });
        }

      
    },),
    UpbuttonIntent: CallbackAction<UpbuttonIntent>(
      onInvoke: (intent) {
        if(usernameFocus!.hasFocus){
         FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(loginButtonFocus);
         setState(() {
           
         });

        }else if(passwordFocus!.hasFocus){
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(usernameFocus);
        setState(() {
          
        });

        }else if(loginButtonFocus!.hasFocus){
         FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(passwordFocus);
         setState(() {
           
         });
        }
      
    },),
    ActivateIntent: CallbackAction<ActivateIntent>(
      onInvoke: (intent) async{
        if(usernameFocus!.hasFocus){
         showCustomKeyboard(context, usernameController);
        }else if(passwordFocus!.hasFocus){
         showCustomKeyboard(context, passwordController);

        }else if(loginButtonFocus!.hasFocus){
          if(formKey.currentState!.validate()){
            UserDataModel user = UserDataModel(username: usernameController.text, password: passwordController.text);
            await context.read<AuthenticationCubit>().login(user);

          }
        }
      
    }),
  }

The problem is that the focus behavior acts with great inconsistency. It goes through the widgets with the right order for 3-4 times then the behavior becomes very unpredictable. I wanted to know what exactly am I doing wrong?

Check if there are overlapping FocusableActionDetector widgets with the same key bindings.

I have only one FocusableActionDetector Widget.
